# QuerySyntaxException: Unexpected token *

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am getting the following error when I try to run a query using **EntityManager**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8
```

What could be causing this?

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myClass");

        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        List<String> results= em.createQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM myClass ")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .getResultList();

}
```

Comment: JPQL != SQL. Suggest you read basic JPA documentation before just dumping a query in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use ***** operator in HQL. You can try like below:

```
List<String> results= em.createQuery(
                "SELECT myclass FROM myClass ")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .getResultList();
```

Hope this helps!